# Error response from daemon: Get "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/": Bad Gateway

Tags: docker, docker-machine

[enter image description here][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQldJ.png**strong text**

Hi, I am new to Docker and trying to run the image but it's not working and giving error response from daemon

Answer (score 0):

simply upgrading to the latest version worked for me.
PS: version 4.13.1 at the time

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33084310)